# How to strip the beginning and end of a message in Python 3.2

Tags: string, python-3.x, serial-port

I am sending a message to python 3.2.

> VT=10000

when 3.2 gets it, it adds on:

> b'VT=10000'

The motors that i am sending this command to don't understand the extra stuff.
***How do i get rid of the b and '?***

I have tried to to use

> string.strip()

but maybe i am using it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean you're "sending a message" to Python? The 'b' and quote characters are just an artifact of printing something, and they just show that you're dealing with a [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html).

Comment: the b was showing up in the message that was passed along by python to an arduino and to an rs232 shield

Comment: Add the code that generates your message and sends it. I can probably help you resolve it if I can see how it's created. It's *very* odd that the b is sent because that should only show up when a bytes object is printed.

Answer (score 0):

The `b` and `'` are showing up because at some point you are treating a `bytes` object as a `str`:

```
>>> incoming = b'vt10000'
>>> command = '%s' % incoming
>>> print(repr(command))
"b'vt10000'"
```